# Passing a vector of unique_ptr to an object. the vector becomes a member variable. correct approach?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

One object I will call "Owner", has clear ownership of a vector of data objects during its lifetime.

These are stored as a vector of unique_ptr.

One object/class, called "Output", needs to look at these data objects in many different methods, and therefore *some kind* of reference / pointer / variable is a member variable of "Output".

Output receives the vector of data objects in its constructor.

I have thought of three ways to achieve this. What would be considered the best way?

**Option 1 - "output" object stores data vec as const reference:**

```
class Output {
    // output wants the data:
 public:
    Output(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Data>> const & in)
        : my_lot_of_data(in) {
    };
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Data>> const & my_lot_of_data;
}
```

which is instantiated by the "Owner" with:

```
 data_vec_.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Data>(new Data));
 /* stuff happens to data */
 Output output(data_vec_);
```

**Option 2 - "output" object stores data vec as const pointer:**

```
class Output {
    // output wants the data:
 public:
    Output(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Data>> const * in)
        : my_lot_of_data(in) {
    };
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Data>> const * my_lot_of_data;
}
```

which is instantiated by the "Owner" with:

```
 data_vec_.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Data>(new Data));
 /* stuff happens to data */
 Output output(&data_vec_);
```

**Option 3 - "output" object receives raw pointers:**

```
class Output {
    // output wants the data:
 public:
    Output(std::vector<Data*> in)
        : my_lot_of_data(in) {
    };
    std::vector<Data*> const my_lot_of_data;
};
```

which is instantiated by the "Owner" with:

```
 data_vec_.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Data>(new Data));
 /* stuff happens to data */
 std::vector<Data*> data_as_raw;
 data_as_raw.resize(data_vec_.size());
 std::transform(data_vec_.begin(), data_vec_.end(), data_as_raw.begin(), [](std::unique_ptr<Data> const & x) {return x.get();});
 Output output(data_as_raw);
```

Additional queries:
In option 1 and 2 is it clear that Output doesnt have ownership of the data, even though it is stored as unique_ptrs?
Is option 3 to messy at the call site? It takes 3 more lines to achieve the same result.

What is best practice here?

Comment: When in doubt, use shared_ptr

Comment: Personally I like `const&`, and don't use `std::transform`. But it could depend on what `Output` does with the data.

Comment: @Barry In my real life situation, Output just reads some of the values, and then creates various output files. No modification of the data.

Comment: @NeilKirk the problem is I keep reading shared_ptr shouldnt be used when there is no lifetime sharing. I know that the object calling the "Output" object is the owner throughout the program lifetime.

Comment: @NeilKirk: strongly disagree.  Excessive use of shared_ptr is a plague and should be avoided.  When in doubt, use unique_ptr.

Comment: The examples make me think you are calling new Data just for Output.

Comment: @KennyOstrom updated to show when things happen to data.

Comment: *the `vector` becomes a member variable* **nope**. The `vector` is not a member, but a member keeps a reference to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using unique_ptr, you don't intend to share this data with anything that could persist longer than Owner, so a simple const reference should be good. I would recommend a nice typedef:

```
typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Data>> OwnerDataSet;
Output(const OwnerDataSet &in)
```

The advantage of approach 1 is that it is simple and clear.  The others just complicate it for no apparent reason.

The function of unique_ptr is to delete the new Data when the std::vector is destructed.  The alternative here would be to copy an instance of Data instead of calling new. If you don't need to work with pointers, then you don't need special handling like unique_ptr to keep them safe.

```
typedef std::vector<Data> OwnerDataSet;
OwnerDataSet results;
Data match = findoneresult();
results.push_back(match); // copy something from Owner
Output (results);
```

And to go a step further, it is not clear from your examples why you are maintaining the std::vector outside of the Output class.  Since you are calling std::unique_ptr(new T) on everything being passed, I suspect you only use it with Output, so you could do this:

```
class Output : public std::vector<Data> {
    void PrintToScreen();
    void WriteToDatabase();
    void OrWhatever();
};

Output x;
Data match = findoneresult();
x.push_back(findoneresult());
x.PrintToScreen();
```

Comment: I'd argue the typedef is necessary when it defines the same type in multiple classes, but it goes away in the last code example I posted because the vector is only defined in one place.

Comment: I have since learned that inheriting from std containers is not recommended (because they do not have a virtual destructor, making this risky with new/delete), so class Output should have the vector as a member (or use private inheritance). Of course, there's no risk with the statically scoped example I posted.

Answer (score 3):

If all you need is to "read some of the values, and then [create] various output files" I would just make it a function that takes by const-ref:

```
void output(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Data>> const& data) {
    // stuff
}
```

I prefer `const&` to `const*` for usage semantics (`data[0]` vs `(*data)[0]`), and definitely prefer both to passing in the raw data - don't give up your explicit ownership for nothing (and in this case it's not even for convenience given that it's pretty annoying to construct a `vector<Data*>` anyway)

Comment: my issue is that the Output class has several functions that all use the same data. Therefore I wanted to have it as a member variable, so that it was obvious all the data is same for each set of output, and so that i wouldnt have to have the data as an argument in each of these functions. Your points regarding the semantics of the const* and the difficulty of creating the raw Data seem very sensible to me.

Answer (score 0):

I would mix the first two approaches: have the Output constructor take the vector by const-ref, but store it as a const pointer.  This is because const pointers can be copied so the entire Output object can be assignable if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I would avoid passing the vector at all and have the vector of unique_ptr encapsulated inside `Owner`. Could the `Output` have a pointer/reference to `Owner` and get raw pointers to the individual `Data` elements from `Owner`?

```
class Owner {
  private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Data>> data_vec_;
  public:
    const Data* getData(size_t i) const { return data_vec_.at(i).get(); }
    size_t getSize() const { return data_vec_.size(); }
};

class Output {
  private:
    const Owner& owner_;   
  public:
    Output(const Owner& owner) : owner_(owner) { }
    void doSomething() { 
         // get some data
         auto data = owner_.getData(0);

         // use data...
    }
};
```

Comment: why this overly complicated design?

Comment: @Walter Firstly, I don't think it is overly complicated. It is much simpler to pass around an `Owner` than a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Data>>`. Secondly, it means you can easily change how the data is stored in the future, e.g to a different container, or to use a shared_ptr.

Comment: This creates a problem for unit testing.  If Output just takes a well known array type, the test is easier than if it must detect any errors that later arises due to changes inside Owner.getData()

Comment: @KennyOstrom If you want to make it easier to unit test you can easily pass an interface instead of a concrete `Owner`.